# This Apple ID has already accepted an invite to this app

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I get this error when importing CSV into iTunes Connect

How do i find which Apple ID has already accepted an invite?

[image]

Comment: There is a list of people on iTunes connect who are assigned as external testers.  Please remember if a member is listed as an Internal tester they CANNOT be an external tester too

Comment: Perhaps you have a notification email letting you know the status of an invite?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out who has installed an app by visiting [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) as admin, choose **Users and Roles** then select the **TestFlight Beta Testers** tab.

A list of internal testers and latest installed apps will be displayed, you can switch between (internal and external).